# Unable to delete some files via System.IO.File in C# console app

Tags: c#, console-application, system.io.file

I am encrypting some text files.  It works fine the file is encypted, however on occasion I get this error when attempting to delete the original unencrypted file:

> *System.IO.IOException: 
>   **The process cannot access the file 'MyFile.TXT' because it is being used by another process.**  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)  at System.IO.File.Delete(String
>   path)  at FileEncryption.Program.DeleteFile(String sInputFilename)  in
>   FileEncryption\Program.cs:line 159*

This seems to happen on large text files. (50MB+) but not always.

***Any idea what I might be doing wrong?***

**Method to PROCESS the folder of txt files:**

```
private static void BeginFileProcessing(string sSecretKey_)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(_sourcePath);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(_fileType);

    try
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string thisFileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);
            string thisFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            string encFileName = String.Format("{0}-enc{1}", thisFileName, thisFileExt);

            if (_TestingOnly)
            {
                Console.Write("Source: " + file.Name + " " + 
                    " Encrypted File: " + encFileName + "\n");
            }

            EncryptFile(file.FullName, _targetPath + encFileName, sSecretKey_);

            if (_DeleteOriginal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deleteing file: " + file.FullName);
                DeleteFile(file.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogWriter(string.Format("\nError Decrypting file: {0}", ex), true);
    }
}
```

**Method to ENCRYPT the files**

```
private static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename, 
    string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
{
    FileStream fsInput = 
        new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    FileStream fsEncrypted = 
        new FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
    ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();

    CryptoStream cryptostream = 
        new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    try
    {
        byte[] bytearrayinput = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sInputFilename);
        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
        cryptostream.Close();
        fsInput.Close();
        fsEncrypted.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = "";

        foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in ex.Data)
        {
            error += pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value + "\n";
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }

        LogWriter(error, true);
    }
}
```

**Method to DELETE the files**

```
private static void DeleteFile(string sInputFilename)
{
    try
    {
        if (_TestingOnly)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TESTING ONLY! File: " + sInputFilename + " would have been deleted.");
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(sInputFilename);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
        LogWriter(ex.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite a bit to read, but the file is locked by another process.  Ie, you open a text file then attempt to delete, while it is open it will throw an error.

Comment: Yeah, it is a lot to read. But rather too much info than not enough. I feel like I am "closing" the file after I encrypt it.

Comment: I have encountered similar file access issues with a particular AV product before. In that case I worked around it by adding some retry logic and a sleep.

Comment: You could implement a `using` and `IDispose` then implement said logic.

Comment: @Greg on what part should I use the Using. I have also never used iDispose before eeek

Comment: You should use `using` on any object that implements `IDisposable`, like all your `Stream` objects and the `DESCryptoServiceProvider`,

Comment: should i just stack the usings? using(filestream){using(filenew){using(DESCrypto){}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by your files not being closed after the call to `EncryptFile`. In your original code, if you hit an exception in `EncryptFile` the streams would be left open if the exception happens before the call to `Close`. Using `Using` statements makes this easier but you can also put the `Close` in a `finally` block and close the streams if they're not null.

Here's an example using `Using`:

```
private static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename, 
    string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
{
    using(FileStream fsInput =  new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {

        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();

        using(CryptoStream cryptostream = 
            new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytearrayinput = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sInputFilename);
                fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
                cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = "";

                foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in ex.Data)
                {
                    error += pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value + "\n";
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }

                LogWriter(error, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

My proposed code will solve the issue of the file stream being left open. However, the root of the issue is that the system throws an `OutOfMemoryException` while reading the file if it's large. The original code would read all the bytes then read the bytes again into the same buffer, which is a waste of memory and a waste of time. Below is a corrected version:

```
private static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename, 
    string sOutputFilename, string sKey)
{
    using(FileStream fsInput =  new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {

        DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();

        using(CryptoStream cryptostream = 
            new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int readCount = 0;

            try
            {
                while ((readCount = fsInput.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)) > 0)
                {
                    cryptostream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = "";

                foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in ex.Data)
                {
                    error += pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value + "\n";
                    Console.WriteLine(error);
                }

                LogWriter(error, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm i tried adding a finally to the try/catch to close the fsInput, fsEnctyped and the cryptoStream. It will close, but then the delete cannot access a closed file.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of how you call `BeginFileProcessing` I'm going to try running the code myself to see if I can spot anything

Comment: BeginFileProcessing is just called in the Main method

Comment: I ran some tests and finally found something. It seems that it was as I expected, the code would throw and exception (`OutOfMemoryException`) while in the `EncryptFile` function, the files streams wouldn't be closed and then the delete would crash. I ran my tests on your original code and on my proposed code and the proposed code would correctly delete the files even when the exception occurred

Comment: See my edit, this should fix your issues. I'm surprised no one noticed that you read all the bytes into a buffer then read all the bytes again the line below.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried you Edited code: I get a Cryptography error: Length of the data to encrypt is invalid. I also had to revise your first 'using' statement as separating the two filestreams with a comma was invalid. I just broke the second out and stacked it.

Comment: That's what I get for copying and pasting...I corrected the issue with the `using` statement, thanks for pointing that out!
As for your issue, I can't say much as when I never encountered that kind of exception while testing. It's possible you have a logic error somewhere. If you post your code I'd be happy to take a look.
If you want to see my test project you can download a copy [here](http://www60.zippyshare.com/v/fPqIlrBW/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `using` statements for all objects that implement `IDisposable`. This will ensure that they are closed and disposed at the end of the `using` block:

```
private static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename, string sOutputFilename, 
    string sKey)
{
    using (var fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.Read))
    using (var fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, FileMode.Create, 
        FileAccess.Write))
    using (var desCryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        desCryptoProvider.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
        desCryptoProvider.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

        using (var encryptor = desCryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, encryptor, 
            CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            try
            {
                var bytearrayinput = File.ReadAllBytes(sInputFilename);
                fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
                cryptoStream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var errors = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var pair in ex.Data)
                {
                    errors.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
                }

                Console.WriteLine(errors.ToString());
                LogWriter(errors.ToString(), true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly an answer, but may help; a simple method to check if a file is locked:

```
bool IsFileAvailable(string fileName)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        stream = fileInfo.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // File is not present, or locked by another process
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    // File is present and not locked
    return true;
}
```